# How to check if several values are in a list in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to make this clause more compact?

```
SELECT campaign
       ,event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*`
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL  -- What does it mean when a campaign is null in Adobe_analytics
AND
(
"1" IN UNNEST(split(event_list,","))
OR "2" IN UNNEST(split(event_list,","))
OR "3" IN UNNEST(split(event_list,","))
)
```

Something like :

```
SELECT campaign
   ,event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*`
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL
AND ("1" OR "2" OR "3") IN UNNEST(split(event_list,","))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
SELECT campaign, event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*` rd
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rd.event_list)) el
              WHERE el IN ('1', '2', '3')
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT campaign ,event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*`
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(event_list,",")) e
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT("1,2,3",",")) e USING(e)
) > 0
```