# BigQuery difference between Struct<INT64> and {INT64}

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to select the `campaigns` for which an `event_list` contains either the events `1` or `2` or `3`. The following code renders an error of type: `No matching signature for operator IN for argument types STRUCT<INT64> and {INT64}`

```
SELECT campaign, event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*` rd
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT CAST(e AS INT64) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rd.event_list)) e) el
              WHERE el IN (1,2,3)
             )
```

In [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635224/how-to-check-if-several-values-are-in-a-list-in-bigquery), an answer suggested by **Gordon Linoff**; the same "kind of query" manipulates `Array<String>` yields a correct result.

Here's the query for comparison :

```
SELECT campaign, event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200*` rd
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rd.event_list)) el
              WHERE el IN ('1', '2', '3')
             );
```

So my questions are :

1. What is `{INT64}`, and how does it differ from `STRUCT<INT64>`
2. How do I correctly fix my query for the wanted result?

EDIT :

Screenshot of the error:
[image: Screenshot of the error within BigQuery]

Comment: did you see another answer on that your previous question? it does not have this issue and does not need to be fixed/corrected. In any case  - it is not clear what you mean by `{INT64}` in context of BigQuery?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you for your response. I tried solving this by using the `EXISTS` operator, and the error caught my interest as I do not know what `{INT64}` is either.

I edited the post to include a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I correctly fix my query for the wanted result?

see fix below

```
SELECT campaign, event_list
FROM `adobe_analytics.raw_data_20200` rd
WHERE campaign IS NOT NULL AND
EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (SELECT CAST(e AS INT64) el FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(rd.event_list)) e)
  WHERE el IN (1,2,3)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is {INT64}, and how does it differ from STRUCT

{INT64} is just INT64, you can ignore the {} around it. In your original query `el` is the whole subquery, that's the reason its type is `STRUCT<INT64>` (a table with an INT64 column) .